# a basic question regarding power electronics

Tags: power-electronics

I understand electronics deals with mainly low voltages, while electrical engineering generally deals with high voltage. Now if we take this as the main difference between the two , where do we put power electronics? Is it a branch of electronics or electrical ?

Also I have seen in many universities power electronics is not taught in electronics engineering courses but definitely in electrical engineering which means it is electrical engineering.

So is there a definite/near definite answer to my question? If yes what is that?

Comment: Electrical engineering is an enormous field with a plethora of subfields from the generation and transmission of electric power, to process control, down to the 14nm fabrication process. People dedicate their entire careers to their chosen subfields. It's all electrical engineering. As you're finding, everyone has an opinion of what to call electrical engineering. Opinions are like elbows, and everybody has them.

Answer (score 1):

The various names for you are using are not standard.  For example, where I went to school (RPI), there was *electrical engineering* and *electric power engineering*.  The first was the kind of circuits you'd find in a TV, for example, while the second was about utility-scale power systems.  I have also heard these two referred to as *electronic engineering* and *electrical engineering*.  Sometimes the term *electronics* applies to the first but not the second, sometimes to everything electrical.

So your question makes no sense without defining how exactly you are using your terms.  What exactly do you mean by "power electronics".  If that is the utility-scale power systems, then it is *electric power engineering*, or whatever it might be called in your area or at your university.  If by "power electronics" you mean things like 200 W class D audio amplifiers or 1 kW inverters, then those would usually be designed by a electrical engineer as apposed to a electric power engineer (or again, whatever your regional terms for those are).

Comment: Can we say power electronics a branch of electronics?

Comment: You can say whatever you want, but without defining your terms that statement would be meaningless.